# Why hive uses RDBMS for storing metastore not filesystem?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to understand design principle behind using RDBMS for Hive Metadata and not filesystem

**From my perspective RDBMS is providing** -

Concurrency control

ACID properties

Sub-second latency etc.

**Filesystem could have provided** -

Replication of data

Concurrency could have been achieved using Zookeeper

Any other thing which impacted this decision during design of Hive?

Comment: RDBMS can do replication fairly simply

Comment: Hive was developed at Facebook. I guess their priority was to make the thing work in their own infrastructure, not to contribute to a Grand Cosmic Plan for the Hadoop ecosystem at large. So, since any RDBMS just works out-of-the-box, why try to develop something else that would have been slow and buggy in the initial release(s)?

Answer (score 3):

you can find out the reason why hive uses RDBMS in the paper : "Hive: a warehousing solution over a map-reduce framework".

---

It describes as following

"The storage system for the metastore should be optimized
for online transactions with random accesses and updates.
A file system like HDFS is not suited since it is optimized
for sequential scans and not for random access. So, the
metastore uses either a traditional relational database (like
MySQL, Oracle) or file system (like local, NFS, AFS) and
not HDFS. As a result, HiveQL statements which only access
metadata objects are executed with very low latency. However,
Hive has to explicitly maintain consistency between
metadata and data."

---

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, they choose this approach of **storing meta information of hive tables in RDBMS**, as opposed to storing this information in hdfs as they need the Meta store(schema, partition, other information) to be very low latency.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons to use RDBMS for storing metadata:
 CRUD operations not possible, 
 Editing files or data present in HDFS is not allowed,
 Metadata Stores metadata using RDBMS to provide low query latency,
 HDFS read/write operations are time-consuming processes.